# Is there a tool to convert a math formula written in C to Python?

Tags: python, c, formula

Sometimes I use Mathematica to derive a formula when the algebra is particularly awful, and then use `CForm[]` to convert the resulting expression to compilable C code.  Quite frequently, I would also like to have this formula in Python.  Is there an existing tool to do this?  As an example, here is a recent formula, and as you can see, it would not be pleasant to convert by hand:

```
(Power(a,5)*M + 2*Power(a,3)*M*r*(-2*M + r) + a*M*Power(r,2)*Power(-2*M + r,2) - 
 Sqrt(-(Power(r,3)*Power(Power(a,2) + r*(-2*M + r),2)*(Power(a,4)*M*(-1 + Power(rd,2)) - 
       Power(a,2)*r*(2*M*r + Power(r,2)*Power(rd,2) + Power(M,2)*(-4 + Power(rd,2))) + 
       M*Power(r,2)*(-4*Power(M,2) + 4*M*r + Power(r,2)*(-1 + Power(rd,2)))))))/((Power(a,2)*M - Power(r,3))*Power(Power(a,2) + r*(-2*M + r),2))
```

Comment: A good, old, search & replace will do the work

Comment: yeah, I was hoping there would be something a little more streamlined.  I often deal with a half-dozen equations of this order of magnitude per script and search&replace gets tiresome.

Comment: what abou using the `sed` utility ?

Comment: You often deal with it? It being a lot of lines? Write a tool, give it a dictionary with C function as Key and corresponding Python function as value. Then replace all :)

Comment: Power() and Sqrt() are not standard C functions

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert anything. Algebraic operators in Python and C have the same precedence order: *, /, +, -, all of them left-to-right. See for example https://montcs.bloomu.edu/Information/operator-precedence.C-Python-Pascal.shtml .

You will only have to define the functions used. In your example I see Power() and Sqrt(), which probably would map to Python's math.pow() and math.sqrt().

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sympy to derive your formula in python and execute in python after.

This is the usual way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you trust the code you could use `exec`

```
from math import sqrt

formula_str = """
def myfunc(a,r,rd,M):
    return (Power(a,5)*M + 2*Power(a,3)*M*r*(-2*M + r) + a*M*Power(r,2)*Power(-2*M + r,2) - 
    Sqrt(-(Power(r,3)*Power(Power(a,2) + r*(-2*M + r),2)*(Power(a,4)*M*(-1 + Power(rd,2)) - 
    Power(a,2)*r*(2*M*r + Power(r,2)*Power(rd,2) + Power(M,2)*(-4 + Power(rd,2))) + 
    M*Power(r,2)*(-4*Power(M,2) + 4*M*r + Power(r,2)*(-1 + Power(rd,2)))))))/((Power(a,2)*M - Power(r,3))*Power(Power(a,2) + r*(-2*M + r),2))
""".replace("Power","pow").replace("Sqrt","sqrt")

myfunc(5,4,3,2) #output:0.6288528754088698
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, just add all the values you want to replace in the dictionary:

```
dict = {
    'Power': 'pow', 
    'Sqrt' : 'sqrt'
    };
input = '(Power(a,5)*M + 2*Power(a,3)*M*r*(-2*M + r) + a*M*Power(r,2)*Power(-2*M + r,2) - Sqrt(-(Power(r,3)*Power(Power(a,2) + r*(-2*M + r),2)*(Power(a,4)*M*(-1 + Power(rd,2)) - Power(a,2)*r*(2*M*r + Power(r,2)*Power(rd,2) + Power(M,2)*(-4 + Power(rd,2))) + M*Power(r,2)*(-4*Power(M,2) + 4*M*r + Power(r,2)*(-1 + Power(rd,2)))))))/((Power(a,2)*M - Power(r,3))*Power(Power(a,2) + r*(-2*M + r),2))'

for key, value in dict.items():
    input = input.replace(key, value)

print(input)
```

This will output:

> (pow(a,5) * M + 2 * pow(a,3) * M * r * (-2 * M + r) + a * M * pow(r,2) * pow(-2 * M + r,2) - sqrt(-(pow(r,3) * pow(pow(a,2) + r * (-2 * M + r),2) * (pow(a,4) * M * (-1 + pow(rd,2)) - pow(a,2) * r * (2 * M * r + pow(r,2) * pow(rd,2) + pow(M,2) * (-4 + pow(rd,2))) + M * pow(r,2) * (-4 * pow(M,2) + 4 * M * r + pow(r,2) * (-1 + pow(rd,2)))))))/((pow(a,2) * M - pow(r,3)) * pow(pow(a,2) + r * (-2 * M + r),2))